# Loop doesn't end upon entering negative number until user finish entering all values.

Tags: java

I want the program to end as soon as user enters a value which is less than zero but this program keep asking all three value then exits.

For instance, if I enter -3, 2, 1, The program doesn't display error after entering -3 for the first height, instead it takes all three values then display the "invalid height" message.

How do I make it program display error message of invalid height as soon as user enters a negative value?

```
//Program Asking user to input three different heights
HeightOne = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Height of First    Tower"));

HeightTwo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Height of Second 
Tower"));

HeightThree = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Height of Third               Tower"));

If (centimeterHeightOne < 0 || centimeterHeightTwo < 0 || centimeterThree < 0) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid height";
}
else 
{
   conditions...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Loop doesn't end upon entering negative number until user finish
>   entering all values.

Because that's exactly what you're doing. If you want to terminate after one negative value, put `if` right after you ask for *each* input:

```
heightOne = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Height of First  Tower"));
if(heightOne < 0) {
    displayError();
    //return; ?
}
heightTwo = ...
if(heightTwo < 0) {
    displayError();
}
...
```

Please follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) and change `HeightOne` to `heightOne`.

Comment: I understand but the problem is I don't want to write down the error message three times. I was wondering if there is any why to put all condition together.

Comment: @user3315642 You don't have to print it three times. When you display the error you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Is there any way we can do it with try/catch Exception handling?

Comment: @user3315642 No. `parseInt` **can** handle negative numbers.

Comment: You could implement your own method, that parses the int first and then throw an exception if its smaller than 0, but I don't see why would you want to do that.

Comment: if the number entered by user is negative, the program should notify the user that he has entered a invalid number.

Comment: @MarounMaroun take a look please at the text file

Comment: @user3315642 I don't understand what's the problem. If the user enters illegal input, you'll display a message and terminate. You can also re-ask for the input again. What's exactly the problem?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I got it. Thanks. It seems too easy. :D I was tryin to do it in some other way to avoid writing extra code. Thanks for the help, the programs works now and displays the error. But if you any other loop that we could use instead of returning 3 values, please let me know.

Comment: @user3315642 You're welcome :) If you want to return the three values you should store them in an array and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the check after every value, something like

```
heightOne = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Height of First Tower"));
if (heightOne < 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid height");
    return;
}
```

The `return` statement aborts the current method and returns, if the current method is `main`, the program stops. If you are not in the `main` method, but you want to forcefully exit the program nevertheless, you can do this by calling `System.exit()`.